# Why are "Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs"

Tags: google-play

I have separate APK for each ABI. I have only three published APKs, each for different ABI, but the Google Play Developer Console warns me that some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs.

The question is: Which one? Aren't the ABIs mutually exclusive?

[image: Google Play Developer Console screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer today. This is quoted from the Developer Console:

> Some devices with Native platforms containing any of [x86] are
>   eligible to receive version 187, which is better optimized for the
>   device's Native Platform, but actually receive version 191 because it
>   has a higher version code and the device supports Native platforms
>   containing any of [armeabi-v7a] either directly (e.g. ARMv7 devices
>   support a superset of ARMv5TE instructions) or indirectly (e.g. some
>   x86 devices support ARMv7 or ARMv5TE via native code translation).
>   This would occur when

That is, x86 can emulate ARM.